# Emailing fillable PDF form on submition

Tags: php, html, pdf

I have a fillable PDF form, and when the user fills out the form and presses submit button I would like that WHOLE PDF (not just the filled fields) to be sent to a specific email address.

There were a few questions discussing a similar weather it is possible or not, the answer is YES it is doable.

Now the question is what are the steps to create such a submit button?

In other words - on submit I want a filled PDF to be sent to a admin's email address.

Answer (score 0):

Set the option in the Submit action of the form to send the whole document.

Note that your users will need Acrobat (any version), or Reader XI or newer. To serve older Reader versions, you would have to assign Extended Rights using Acrobat (Save as other… --> Reader enhanced PDF).